# When multiplying by the conjugate of a radical to simply, why is the arithmetic operator positive here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

So,
$$\frac{\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}-\sqrt[2]{6x+17}}{h}$$

then this is where I am confused, not when multiplying by the conjugate to rationalize, the subtraction becomes addition.

$$\frac{\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}-\sqrt[2]{6x+17}}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}+\sqrt[2]{6x+17}}{\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}+\sqrt[2]{6x+17}}$$

then you can simply treat the numerator as raised to the power of two
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt[2]{6x+17}\right)^2}{h\cdot\left(\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}+\sqrt[2]{6x+17}\right)}$$

simplify and cancel h

$$\frac{6h}{h\cdot\left(\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}+\sqrt[2]{6x+17}\right)}$$
$$\frac{6}{\sqrt[2]{6x+6h+17}+\sqrt[2]{6x+17}}$$

Why is the conjugate positive?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the conjugate is positive or negative. All that matters is that when you multiply $u+v$ and $u-v$ you get $u^2-v^2$.

Comment: I understand that, but the denominator is now positive instead of negative.

Comment: So what? Why does that matter?

Comment: Ok actually it makes more sense now since  +  and  −  to get a perfect square thats why the denominator is positive.